# if else statement inside AJAX success not working normally

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Inside my AJAX `success` function there is an `if`/`else` statement. The response coming from the server side is OK but when I check here the `if` logic runs along with the `else` part logic. Both runs at the same time which is a little confusing to me.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'centre-upload-process2.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
      success: function (response) {

        if(response == 'success') {
            $('#centreformupload').hide();
            $('#centreformpayment').show();
            console.log(typeof response);
        } else {
            alert("Already present");
            console.log(typeof response);
        }


        },

        contentType: false,
        processData: false
});
```

PHP

```
<?php require_once '../core/class_init.php'; ?>

<?php 

$centre_uploads = new dbhandler();


$flag = false;
$client_id = $_POST['client_id'];
$r_id = $_POST['r_id'];

$path = new uploads();

$payment_data = $centre_uploads->all_data('payment_dtls');
$i = 0;
foreach($payment_data as $pd) {



    if($payment_data[$i]->fy == input::get('fy')) {

        $flag = true;

    }
}







if(isset($_POST) && isset($_FILES)) {


//$r_id = $_POST['r_id'];


$inputtext2 = $_POST['inputtext2'];
$inputfile2 = $path->upload_image('inputfile2');

$inputtext3 = $_POST['inputtext3'];
$inputfile3 = $path->upload_image('inputfile3');

$inputtext4 = $_POST['inputtext4'];
$inputfile4 = $path->upload_image('inputfile4');


if(empty($inputtext2) && empty($inputfile2)) {

    $inputtext2 = 'NA';
    $inputfile2 = 'NA';


} 

if(empty($inputtext3) && empty($inputfile3)) {

    $inputtext3 = 'NA';
    $inputfile3 = 'NA';


} 


if(empty($inputtext4) && empty($inputfile4)) {

    $inputtext4 = 'NA';
    $inputfile4 = 'NA';


}




if(!$flag) {
   try{
        $centre_uploads->create('payment_dtls' , array(

            'r_id' => $r_id,
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'fy' => input::get('fy'),
            'ay' => input::get('ay')
        ));

        $centre_uploads->create('upload_dtls' , array(
             'r_id' => $r_id,
             'client_id' => $client_id,
             'pan_file' => $path->upload_image('pan_file'),
             'bank_file' => $path->upload_image('bank_file'),
             'insurance_file' => $path->upload_image('insurance_file'),
             'title1' => $inputtext2,
             'document1_file' => $inputfile2,
             'title2' => $inputtext3,
             'document2_file' => $inputfile3,
             'title3' => $inputtext4,
             'document3_file' => $inputfile4,
             'purpose' => input::get('purpose')
         ));


        echo 'success';



    }catch(Exception $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

} else {
    echo 'denied';
}


}
```

If the response is 1 then data gets inserted to database but I also get an `alert` and the logic written on response 1 here does not work(the from doesn't hide) instead I get an alert.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the value `'1'` or `1`? Ie. a string or an integer

Comment: Use `typeof` to determine the type of the response as Rory McCrossan said.

Comment: i tried using plain string such as 'success' and 'denied'.... still no use

Comment: The fact you're seeing both the `if` and the `else` execute implies that you're actually firing two AJAX requests. The first one insert data, the second throw the already exists error. Check the network tab of the console to see what's being sent. Also note that `async: false` is considered incredibly bad practice. You should remove it.

Comment: remove `async: false`. i head one guy used it and then ... something terrible happened

Comment: @dsfq sorry tried that...still same issue

Comment: @AbhijitBorkakoty, what is the actual response that you get? I mean, what output do you get when you do `console.log(response);` ? You can try and compare with `1` or `'1'` or `'success'` or `'denied'`, but if the actual `response` is different then there is your problem.

Comment: @lonut if data gets inserted i get a response 1 along with an alert...if data doesnt get inserted i get a response 0 along with an alert....both cases i get an alert

Comment: @AbhijitBorkakoty, ok. And if you do a `console.log(typeof response);` what output do you get?

Comment: @lonut i am using 'success' and 'denied' now and getting a typeof string

Comment: @AbhijitBorkakoty, stick to `success` only. Where do you put the `success` string? Please update your question with the `PHP` also.

Comment: Your AJAX-Request gets fired twice. First with an empty response (->`else`) and the second time with your `"1"` as the response (->`if`)

Comment: @lonut please check the updated post

Comment: @Andy sorry what? i din't understand what you said..

Comment: The AJAX-Request you posted above gets executed twice. I need the JS to say why and where but that's a fact. Check your console output: You have once the output with an empty line and the second time your `"1"`

Comment: @Andy yes there is an empty line ...so how do I fix this...should i paste the js code?

Comment: I think this would help, yes. The line is cause by the `console.log(response);`-Line in your `else`-clause since you get however an empty result the first time the AJAX-Request gets executed.

Comment: @Andy So how do i fix this??

Comment: I have to take a look on your JS

Comment: May you make a https://jsfiddle.net/ with your JS and HTML to avoid large questions

Comment: Here is the link https://jsbin.com/zekerosoyu/edit?js

Comment: PLease also add your HTML-Code to the jsbin

Comment: https://jsbin.com/zekerosoyu/1/edit?html,js

Comment: Works fine on my computer... Can you 1) place a `console.log("foo");` inside your `.submit()`-Function and watch how many times this gets outputted? and 2) add/update the following line `$('#centreformupload').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); etc...` and additionally add `action="#"` to your `<form>`-Tag

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your response is an integer 1, not a string '1'.  You could double check exactly what is being returned by adding:

```
console.log(response, typeof response)
```

Your test:

```
if (response === '1') {
```

requires that `response` is the string '1', the number 1 will not match.  So processing in `centre-upload-process2.php` is working fine, records added to the DB, and it returns integer 1.  That's not the string the Javascript expects, so it is interpreted as an error, and your alert is shown.

Assuming this is true and you are getting an integer back, update your JS to expect an integer:

```
if (response === 1) {
```